# How to resample timedeltas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been running an experiment that outputs data with two columns:

1. seconds since start of experiment (float)
2. a measurement. (float)

I would now like to load this into Pandas to resample and plot the measurements. I've done this before, but those times my timestamps have been since epoch or in datetime (YYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss) format. If I'm loading my first column as integers I'm unable to do

```
data.resample('5Min', how='mean')
```

. It also does not seem possible if I'd convert my first column to `timedelta(seconds=...)`. My question is, is it possible to resample this data without subverting to epoch conversion?

Comment: can you post some of your data? hard to help otherwise

Comment: What date format are you using (it should always be Timestamp?)

Comment: why not converting your first column to timedelta? by definition "seconds since start of experiment" is timedelta when time 0 is the start of the experiment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `time // period` to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t = np.random.rand(10000)*3600
t.sort()
v = np.random.rand(10000)

df = pd.DataFrame({"time":t, "value":v})

period = 5*60
s = df.groupby(df.time // period).value.mean()
s.index *= period
```

Comment: Is there a way to resample like this if the time column contains datetimes rather than ints? I tried using this with datetimes and got `TypeError: incompatible type for a datetime/timedelta operation [__floordiv__]`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same structure  of sensors data. First column is seconds since start of the experiment and rest of columns are value.
here is the data structure:

```
              time        x           y          z
      0     0.015948    0.403931    0.449005    -0.796860
      1     0.036006    0.403915    0.448029    -0.795395
      2     0.055885    0.404907    0.446548    -0.795853
```

here is what worked for me:
**convert the time to time delta:**

```
df.time=pd.to_timedelta(df.time,unit="s")
```

**`set the time as index`**

```
df.set_index("time",inplace=True)
```

**resample to the frequency you want**

```
df.resample("40ms").mean()
```

Comment: Hi, I tried df.time = pd.to_timedelta(df.time, unit="s"), why am I getting AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time' ?

Comment: I think it is because time is a known attribute of an object in python , so try df["time"] instead