# Trouble resampling Pandas timeseries data on Python timedelta objects

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I'm having trouble resampling Pandas timeseries data when working with `timedelta` objects.  Pandas will happily compute the mean of a Series of `timedelta`s, but seems to trip up when resampling that same Series.

```
# a Series of timedeltas
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100, freq='D')
r = [timedelta(hours=i) for i in np.random.random(len(rng))]
ts = pd.Series(r, index=rng)

ts.mean()  # fine

# DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
ts.resample('M', how='mean')

# this is better, but ..
ts.resample('M', how=pd.Series.mean)   # works. Hurrah.
ts.resample('T', how=pd.Series.mean)   # fail: Must produce aggregated value
```

Passing the function `pd.Series.mean` directly to `resample` works - for some data, but trips up, for example if a sampling bucket has no values (e.g. on minutes `T` above). I expect that's why it's better to pass `'mean'` and let Pandas do the right thing. Only `'mean'` appears not to select a suitable function in this case.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270012/how-to-resample-timedeltas) eludes to the same problem and proposes a `groupby`. That strikes me more of a workaround(?) This way looks like it *should* work, but what am i missing?     (Pandas 0.14)

Comment: as an aside, it doesn't make sense to upsample to 'T' which is minutely frequency.

Comment: for sure, agree this is a somewhat ridiculous example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not implemented at the moment, though coming in 0.14.1 (see this [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6884)

As a work-around you can do this:

```
In [1]: rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100, freq='D')

In [2]: r = [timedelta(hours=i) for i in np.random.random(len(rng))]

In [3]: ts = pd.Series(r, index=rng)

In [4]: ts
Out[4]: 
2000-01-01   00:03:10.322420
2000-01-02   00:24:59.112675
2000-01-03   00:32:14.511518
2000-01-04   00:52:58.694410
2000-01-05   00:18:29.775375
2000-01-06   00:12:39.262857
2000-01-07   00:33:27.589009
2000-01-08   00:55:25.054240
2000-01-09   00:20:47.593920
2000-01-10   00:30:10.429640
2000-01-11   00:59:28.416187
2000-01-12   00:25:52.223876
2000-01-13   00:15:44.470747
2000-01-14   00:43:24.809208
2000-01-15   00:08:12.211051
...
2000-03-26   00:40:14.156113
2000-03-27   00:06:28.998191
2000-03-28   00:08:35.440506
2000-03-29   00:33:26.654861
2000-03-30   00:34:39.304583
2000-03-31   00:10:20.184603
2000-04-01   00:50:13.484530
2000-04-02   00:40:11.975429
2000-04-03   00:04:36.064879
2000-04-04   00:42:54.793764
2000-04-05   00:58:30.588331
2000-04-06   00:34:17.431583
2000-04-07   00:34:55.479245
2000-04-08   00:47:24.305921
2000-04-09   00:14:42.699607
Freq: D, Length: 100
```

This groups by the month, then performs the mean:

```
In [5]: ts.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).apply(lambda x: x.mean()[0])
Out[5]: 
2000-1-31    00:32:13.413522
2000-2-29    00:26:06.009614
2000-3-31    00:31:57.965306
2000-4-30    00:36:25.202588
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeff that's a neat solution. Appreciated.